# Why Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx is coming in dependency - UWP APPX

Tags: uwp, appx

When I was used to create appx file (x64 release mode) of my project , there was only Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx file was created under dependency folder. But now when I'm trying to create appx, an additional file "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx" is also creating under dependency folder. What is the reason for it? And How can I remove it? Now when clients run my appx (using AppInstaller) , it shows

> "App installer failed to install package dependencies. Ask the
>   developer for Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 package"

This issue can be resolved when they install Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx seperately. But clients are not interested to do it. So how can I stop generating Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx in dependency folder?

Comment: Just to be clear... This is not a managed code project? Are you using any 3rd party libraries that might be managed (like XAML controls etc)?

Comment: using c# and xaml. When I was creating package previously this Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 package was not created.

Comment: It's needed for managed code. I don't know why you didn't get a reference previously.

Comment: I too have no idea why it is not generated previously. Is there any way to install it without manually ? using app installer/?